# LinkedIn share button uses wrong image

Tags: wordpress, plugins, linkedin-api, share, share-button

I developed a custom plugin for wordpress. In my plugin I´m using a linkedIn share button but when I try to share the article, linkedIn uses the wrong image. What have I done wrong? I tryed several solutions. og:image etc. are set correctly but I don´t know why it is not working.

Here is a link to the page:
https://www.vdtev.de/artikel?/event/vdt-treasury-online-mentoring/790

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cache may be out of date for the link you are trying to share. Use the [Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) to test sharing the link and to cache the latest changes.

Comment: I have done this already. The wrong image is displayed.